# How can I get a view from a Context in Android?

Tags: android, helper, android-context

in my project I am passing a context of an activity to a helper class. Now, is it possible to use that context and find the views from that activity? Basically, I would like to find the views by id, but just using a context object.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to inflate that view in order to find any view.

Comment: I think the LayoutInflater is what you are looking for. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Answer (score 3):

Provided you stored your context in a private reference, do this (MonoDroid)

```
View parent = ((Activity)_context).Window.DecorView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
```

In Raw Android it'd look something like:

```
View parent = ((Activity)mContext).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

Activity is a Context, so if you actually pass your Activity to a helper class, you can just:

```
 void someMethodInHelperClass(Context c) {
  if(c instanceof Activity) {
   ((Activity)c).findViewById(R.id.someviewid);
  }
 }
```

Of course it will be much easier if you change your method to:

```
 void someMethodInHelperClass(Activity c) {
```